# How to count consecutive days for a certain event in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to count number of consecutive days in python to count : number of previous days_by store , by SKU_where there was no sales and at same time there was available stock at this store. I tried many codes and answers but with no resolution. Here is the data i have and the latest column is what i exactly need "Blackhole Counter".
[image]

the code that i used as follows

```
pd.to_numeric(df['store'])
pd.to_numeric(df['item'])
pd.to_numeric(df['Blackhole'])
Dynamic_Quantites['DateFormat'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'])


df['BlackholeCounter'] = df.groupby(['store', 'item' , 'Blackhole' ])['DateFormat'].rank(method='first').reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Another trial

```
s = df.groupby('ItemKey_Concatenated').DateFormat.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()
df['new_frame'] = df.groupby(['ItemKey_Concatenated', s]).size().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

where ItemKey_Concatenated = concatenation between store and item
```

Another trial

```
df['DateFormat'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateFormat'], dayfirst=True)

df2 = df.sort_values(['ItemKey_Concatenated', 'DateFormat'])
s = df2.groupby('ItemKey_Concatenated').DateFormat.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()
new_frame = df2.groupby(['ItemKey_Concatenated', s]).size().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='count')

result = pd.merge(Dynamic_Quantites,new_frame, on=["ItemKey_Concatenated","ItemKey_Concatenated"] , how ="left")
```

Appreciate your experience and support in this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to simulate your `df`, please be kind to add a sample df next time.

Lists for the df:

```
BlackHoles = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
date=[Timestamp('2022-09-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-06 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-08 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-09 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-10 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-16 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-17 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-18 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-20 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-22 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-09-23 00:00:00')]
```

DataFrame like above:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'date' : new_list, 'BlackHoles' : BlackHoles})
```

Now I'm assigning a tool to identify any "shifts" on the value of BlackHoles:

```
tool = (df['BlackHoles']!=df['BlackHoles'].shift()).cumsum()
```

Whenever I have a breakpoint / shift on column values, `cumsum()` will separate it in groups.*

After that, I just add the new created column to our df.  `cumcount() + 1`, to avoid zeros on values.

```
df['BlackHoles_Cum']=df.groupby(tool)['BlackHoles'].cumcount()+1
```

**More about it on [pandas Cookbook](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html)  : Grouping like Python’s itertools.groupby*